Edit table data through a directory in lua
I have a table and a directory :
--directory
{
[1] = "File"
[2] = "Documents"
[3] = "txt_Page"
}

--Table for directory
{
Files = {
    File = {
        Documents = {
            txt_Page = "new"
            }
        }
    }
}

I want to edit the txt_page through the directory and return the newly edited files table but I've tried methods and I can't seem to find it.

this is not a coding service. post your solution attempt and explain how it is behaving from what you expect.  also fi your data structure contains more than one file you should provide and example of at at least 2-3 files. as is your post doesn't make any sense to me

Just concat it:
tabl = {"File", "Documents", "txt_page"}
path = table.concat(tabl, "/")
print(path)  -- "File/Documents/txt_page"

For Lua table:
local new_txt_Page = 3
local str = "Files['" .. table.concat(tabl, "']['") .. "'] = " .. new_txt_Page
print (str) -- Files['File']['Documents']['txt_Page'] = 3 
load(str)() -- execute the string

If your strings have no spaces dashes etc., then you can make it just like:
str = "Files."..table.concat(tabl, ".").." = ".. new_txt_Page
print (str) -- Files.File.Documents.txt_Page = 3
load(str)()


If you mean that the names of the fields in the second table are taken from the first table, then so:
--directory
local dir = {
[1] = "File",
[2] = "Documents",
[3] = "txt_Page",
}

--Table for directory
local t= {
Files = {
    File = {
        Documents = {
            txt_Page = "new"
            }
        }
    }
    }

print (t.Files[dir[1]][dir[2]][dir[3]]t)

out:
new


this would work but i could have 9 nested tables and it wouldn't be very efficient and would require a lot of if statements

then clarify in the question where and what you have a variable quantity, you may need function with loop iteration to access the value
